# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain using arcgis api for javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, arcgis

Using arcgis api for javascript to add a map,but the chrome console report an error that is

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/plain:
>   "http://localhost/gisSystem/proxy/proxy.ashx?http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rerue&format=png8&callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript2._jsonpCallback"

I found the similar questions but i can not figure out my problem.Does anybody who konws how to solve this ploblem,I would be great thankful!

Comment: its a warning, not an error, the script should still work.

Comment: yeah,I know it does work normal,so this warning just ignore?

Comment: since its just for your localhost and not public. its not something that needs fixing.